# Am I using the replacement axiom correctly to show that if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, then the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ is a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

**Exercise 3.5.1.** (omitting irrelevant portions)

Suppose we *define* the ordered pair $(x,y)$ for any objects $x$ and $y$ by the formula $(x,y):=\{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\}$ $\ldots$ Show that $\ldots$ whenever $X$ and $Y$ are sets, the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ is also a set.

---

**Source.**

Analysis I, Terrance Tao, 3rd edition.

---

**What I've tried.**

In order to show the above, I first need to show that the following set exists

$$
\{(x,y) : y \in Y\}
$$

with $x \in X$ fixed.

I will show this by using the replacement axiom which is given by the following

> **Axiom 3.7** (Replacement)**.** Let $A$ be a set. For any object $x \in A$, and any object $y$, suppose we have a statement $P(x,y)$ pertaining to $x$ and $y$, such that for each $x \in A$ there is at most one $y$ for which $P(x,y)$ is true. Then there exists a set $\{y : P(x,y) \ \text{is true for some} \ x \in A \}$, such that for any object $z$,
> $$
> z \in \{y : P(x,y) \ \text{is true for some} \ x \in A \} \iff P(x,z) \ \text{is true for some} \ x \in A
> $$

Below are two questions I need cleared up before I move on to construct the next set which should be $\{\{(x,y) : y \in Y\}: x \in X\}$.

**Question 1.** Is the below informal reasoning on how the replacement axiom will be used to show $\{(x,y) : y \in Y\}$ exists correct?

> We replace every $y \in Y$ by $(x,y)$ where $x \in X$ is fixed.

**Question 2.** Below I attempt to rigorously use the replacement axiom to show $\{(x,y) : y \in Y\}$ exists. Have I used it correctly? I'm concerned the set I end up with isn't what I sought out to show exists.

> For any $y \in Y$ and any ordered pair $(x,b)=\{\{x\}, \{x,b\}\}$ where $x \in X$ is fixed, we define the statement
> $$
> P(y, (x,b)) := b \in \left(\bigcup (x,y)\right) \backslash \{x\} = \{y\}
> $$
> Indeed, for each $y \in Y$, there is at most one $(x,b)$ such that $P(y, (x,b))$ is true, namely $(x,b) = (x,y)$. Thus, by the replacement axiom, the following set exists
> $$
> \{(x,b) : b \in \{y\} \ \text{for some} \ y \in Y\}
> $$

Comment: You don't need replacement for that; since $X\times Y\subseteq\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X\cup Y))$ you can get by with pairing, union, power set, and separation.

Comment: When you write $\bigcup (x,y)$, do you simply mean $\bigcup (x,y) = \bigcup \{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\} = \{x\} \cup \{x, y\} = \{x, y\}$?

Comment: @CrabMan yes correct

Comment: @user14111 good point, I’ll try that approach after I’ve tried it this way.

Comment: @user14111 on the other hand, you don’t need power set for that… the proof with replacement works in KP, for instance.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I thought Replacement was a big gun that was needed for Advanced Set Theory, while Power Set is something we all use every day. But I'm not a logician (as you can tell) and I don't know what KP is.

Comment: I convinced myself that my definition of the statement $P$ is not well-intented. Would it be better to say instead that for every $y$ in $Y$ and any set $S$, we define $P(y,S):= S = (x,y)$ for a fixed $x \in X$? This would grant the existence of the set $\{S: S=(x,y) \ \text{for some} \ y \in Y\}$, which I claim is just $\{(x,y):y \in Y\}$.

Comment: @user14111 they’re both the big gun in their own way. But you’re right that dropping power set is mostly of interest to logicians whereas most of everyday math can be done (if sometimes clumsily) without replacement.